# Access SQL Query - How to include all records from both table intersecting dates, currently excluding certain rows from query not sure why

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on an Access database of Price and Discount information,
I thought I had figured it out but just noticed that it actually is still excluding one record of my data from my query and I'm not entirely sure why. Here's what I have (I just made a small set for testing)

1st table is discount info,
2nd table is price info,
3rd table is my ideal results,
4th table is my current results

| SKU | Start | End | PID | DID | AMT | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 5/12/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 2001 | 2001-001 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 5/12/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 2001 | 2001-002 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 2 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |

| SKU | Flavor | Start | End | Price | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |
| 4 | Peach | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |
| 4 | Peach | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |
| 4 | Peach | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |

| SKU | Flavor | STD | END | FL | FOB | STD | END | PID | DID | AMT | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/12/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 2001 | 2001-002 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | Peach | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Peach | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Peach | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

| SKU | Flavor | STD | END | FL | FOB | STD | END | PID | DID | AMT | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 1 | Cherry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 | 5/3/2022 | 5/7/2022 | 2000 | 2000-001 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/12/2022 | 5/14/2022 | 2001 | 2001-002 | 1.5 | 5 |
| 2 | Strawberry | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 3 | Watermelon | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 | 5/17/2022 | 5/28/2022 | 2002 | 2002-001 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | Peach | 5/1/2022 | 5/11/2022 | 20 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Peach | 5/12/2022 | 5/27/2022 | 24 | 12 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | Peach | 5/28/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 28 | 14 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My SQL code running in Access:

```
SELECT PC.SKU, PC.Flavor, DC.STD, DC.END, DC.DID, DC.AMT, DC.QTY, PC.STD, PC.END, PC.FL, PC.FOB
FROM PC LEFT OUTER JOIN DC ON PC.SKU = DC.SKU
WHERE (([DC]![STD]>=[PC]![STD] And [DC]![STD]<=[PC]![END]) 
OR ([DC]![END]>=[PC]![STD] And [DC]![END]<=[PC]![END]) 
OR ([DC]![STD] IS NULL AND [DC]![END] IS NULL));
```

I'd like to see the price for the item even if it does not have discounts, and I'd like to see all the discounts even though it will duplicate the rows of some prices.
I got this SQL syntax to work almost perfectly, but then noticed that there is no price for item 3 (Watermelon) from 5/1/22 - 5/11/22 in my current results, because there isn't a discount for that time. Because it is currently resulting the item 4, I'm not sure why it is excluding this one row. Anyone have any tips?

Simply, I'd like to see another row if there is a single day overlapping in either date range.
If one discount is starting on the same day as the price ends, I'd still like that result.
I'm somewhat new to SQL, any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly looking for help figuring out why the one row of SKU 3 ( WATERMELON ) is not appearing in my current results. Price dates from 5/1/22 - 5/11/22 are currently not showing, but SKU 4 ( PEACH) is still providing price results even though the discount dates are following the isnull criteria

Comment: So the STD fields are really the Start fields? What are FL and FOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that DC.STD is never null for Watermelon because there are other rows that satisfy the join condition. This is not the case with Peach.

You can fix the problem by moving all the conditions involving the outer table to the ON clause

```sql
SELECT PC.SKU, PC.Flavor, DC.STD, DC.END, DC.DID, DC.AMT, DC.QTY, PC.STD, PC.END, PC.FL, PC.FOB
FROM
    PC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DC
        ON
            (PC.SKU = DC.SKU AND
              (
                (DC.STD>=PC.STD And DC.STD<=PC.[END]) OR
                (DC.[END]>=PC.STD And DC.[END]<=PC.[END])
              )
            );
```

We can even remove the IS NULL parts, since this is handled by the LEFT OUT JOIN automatically.

Note that overlapping of date ranges must be tested with

```sql
DC.STD <= PC.[END] AND DC.[END] >= PC.STD
```

I.e., the start of DC must be before or equal to the end of PC and the end of DC must be after or equal to the start of PC. Because you could have `DC.STD < PC.STD AND DC.[END] > PC.[END]` and these dates would overlap but fall through your test.

```
PC    |----------|
DC  |---------------|
```

So, the correct query is

```sql
SELECT PC.SKU, PC.Flavor, DC.STD, DC.END, DC.DID, DC.AMT, DC.QTY, PC.STD, PC.END, PC.FL, PC.FOB
FROM
    PC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DC
        ON
            (PC.SKU = DC.SKU AND
             DC.STD <= PC.[END] AND DC.[END] >= PC.STD);
```

---

The Access query designer sometimes messes up this ON clause. So, you  should store this query in a safe place in addition to a stored query.

Comment: Output has 5 SKU 2 records, not 3. Is that acceptable? Not seeing the 'overlapping dates' criteria used. How would it look in query - use AND operator? Tried, no change in output. Can't switch to DesignView.

Comment: Is there actually any way to have it also include an entire blank row of the PC line for each SKU with no DC similar to how the Peach is displayed? I finally got this applied to my large set of data and started to filter and check a few things, but when I apply a bunch of filters saying it can't have a discount amount greater than 1, has to be within 1 date range, etc, it makes it so certain instances, item 2 will not have a single row result. Lets say for item 2 I wanted to make a filter of no discounts more than $0.50, then it is also excluded from my reports

Comment: The problem I really ran into now is that some items only have discounts for a specific customer, so when I filter it to exclude customer-specific discounts (eg if I'm preparing a list for everyone in our company), it also excludes the price info.

Comment: To have empty records on both sides, one would use a Full outer join; however, Access doesn't have this. But you can obtain the same result with a union query that goes like this (roughly sketched): SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM b LEFT JOIN a WHERE a.id IS NULL. For your other problems: Instead of having a condition in the WHERE or ON clause, you can have conditions in the SELECT list not discarding rows. Eg.: `SELECT IIf(customer.discount <= 1, customer.discount, 0) as discount, ...`